# how do i get UTC time in batch file (or msdos) ? instead of systems time format

Tags: batch-file, dos

**how to i get UTC time in batch file (or msdos)?**
instead of systems time format

not like dd/MMM/yyyy

Comment: You seem to be confusing two different things, a *value* and its *display format*. I guess that might be because you want both to change the system time to UTC time and to display it in a different format. Still, you should understand the difference. And in any event, batch scripting has probably very poor means for achieving any of your two goals.

Answer (score 3):

Without doing your own date math, there isn't a good way in pure batch.  The only time function available is `time /t` or `%time%` and they don't give any locality information, so you'd end up needing to query the registry, too.

Powershell can do it, though, and you can write a tiny script to get the info you want and pass it out to your batchfile.

```
Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat %y%m%d%H%M%j
```

(from a discussion here: http://www.powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aft/4361/Default.aspx)

You could do the same idea with javascript or vbs.

Comment: Just to help other googlers: To get the date in ISO-format, use e.g. `Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%MZ"`. 

To get the date from a cmd-window (on a computer with powershell, which is to say almost any windows computer): 
`powershell -comand Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%MZ"`

Comment: @dpnmn minor fix on the spelling of "command": `powershell -command Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%MZ"`

Comment: If you want the seconds as well: `Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -uformat "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%SZ"` Example output: `2021-12-08T01-02-03Z`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert a date to its Julian Day Number starting at 1961 (when UTC was officially initiated, that is, UTC day 0 time 00:00:00 was the first instant of 1 January 1961), you may use these Batch files.

DATETOJULIAN.BAT:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM GET MONTH, DAY, YEAR VALUES
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=/" %%A IN ("%1") DO SET MM=%%A& SET DD=%%B& SET YY=%%C
REM ELIMINATE LEFT ZEROS
SET /A DD=10%DD% %% 100, MM=10%MM% %% 100
REM CALCULATE JULIAN DAY NUMBER
IF %MM% LSS 3 SET /A MM+=12, YY-=1
SET /A A=YY/100, B=A/4, C=2-A+B, E=36525*(YY+4716)/100, F=306*(MM+1)/10, JDN=C+DD+E+F-1524
```

DATETOUTC.BAT:

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL DATETOJULIAN %1
SET UTCDAY=%JDN%
CALL DATETOJULIAN 1/1/1961
SET /A UTCDAY-=JDN
ECHO %UTCDAY%
```

For example:

```
DATETOUTC %DATE%
18484
```

Reference: http://quasar.as.utexas.edu/BillInfo/JulianDatesG.html

Answer (score 0):

Its simple but I use this:

```
'Create a string to be used for file name that is the current date time stamp
dtmYear = Year(Date)

dtmMonth = Month(Date)
If Len(dtmMonth) = 1 Then dtmMonth = "0" & dtmMonth

dtmDay = Day(Date)
If Len(dtmDay) = 1 Then dtmDay = "0" & dtmDay

dtmHour = Hour(Now)
If Len(dtmHour) = 1 Then dtmHour = "0" & dtmHour

dtmMinute = Minute(Now)
If Len(dtmMinute) = 1 Then dtmMinute = "0" & dtmMinute

dtmSecond = Second(Now)
If Len(dtmSecond) = 1 Then dtmSecond = "0" & dtmSecond

strUTCDate = dtmYear & dtmMonth & dtmDay & dtmHour & dtmMinute & dtmSecond
```